# Is cygwin possible to install epoll.h on win10?

Tags: compilation, ide, cygwin, epoll

I compile a linux network project with cygwin32 on win10.
The reason for doing this is that I can use comfortable IDE coding envrionment and donot need switch to linux environment to do real-time compilation.
Cygwin shows non-found file error.

```
fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <sys/epoll.h>
```

Does this mean epoll is something only available in the linux 2.6 kernel?
Cygwin has most but not all linux feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not available on any Cygwin package

```
$ cygcheck -p sys/epoll.h
Found 0 matches for sys/epoll.h
```

Cygwin can emulate most of the Linux user space, but it is NOT an exact replica, and it
is limited on the underlying Microsoft engine for some feature